# Subgroup of ${\rm Sp}_4(2)$ isomorphic to $A_5$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

It is well known that ${\rm Sp}_4(2)\cong S_6$.

$S_6$ contains two conjugacy classes of $A_5$ (am I right?): one stabilizing a point and other acting transitively on six points.

Let $\rho_i:A_5\rightarrow {\rm Sp}_4(2)$ ($i=1,2$) be the representations of $A_5$ coming via two different embeddings of $A_5$ in $S_6$ composed with the isomorphism $S_6\rightarrow {\rm Sp}_4(2)$.

**Question:** Are $\rho_1, \rho_2$ inequivalent? irreducible?

Comment: Do you have a reference for ${\rm Sp}_4(2)\cong S_6$ ?

Comment: It is not hard to prove that they are irreducible - try it yourself.

Comment: @Alphonse: I saw this in notes of Cameron on Classical groups (available online).